# Construct a continuous function which has no derivative almost everywhere.

Tags: analysis, derivatives, continuity, almost-everywhere

**Georg Cantor** is famous for the first set theory (in "naive" terms) and the diagonal argument.

However Cantor is also credited with the Cantor Set and for [constructing a continuous function which has no derivative almost everywhere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function).

How can one construct such a function?

Moreover how can one reason in order to come up with such a construction?

Thank you.

Comment: You want to say "zero derivative", not "no derivative", I think...

Comment: maybe i did not phrase this well, the question is about continous function that its derivative is undefined almost everywhere, or does not exist almost everywhere, not that its value could be zero almost everywhere

Comment: Yes Cantor constructed a function with zero derivative, its a step function on the complement of the Cantor set, also called the devil's stairway.

Comment: ok if "zero derivative" means "no derivative" then it is fine, wikipedia states "*On the other hand, it has no derivative at any point in an uncountable subset of the Cantor set containing the interval endpoints described above*"

Comment: In fact "most" functions in $C^0([a,b], \Bbb R )$ will do the trick. This is one of the first exercises in Kerich's Introduction to Descriptive Set Theory and also proved here http://scholarworks.gsu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1043&context=math_theses

Comment: As an application of then newly developed methods in functional analysis, Banach gave a very short existence proof of continuous functions whose points of differentiability form a set of Lebesgue measure zero on p. 43 of his 1926 paper [*Sur la convergence presque partout des fonctionnelles*](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k4862772). See also pp. 43-44 of his 1932 book [**Théorie des Opérations Linéaires**](http://kielich.amu.edu.pl/Stefan_Banach/e-operations.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [Weierstrass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) function.  The function is a Fourier series with higher and higher frequencies.  The terms are $a^n \cos (b^n \pi x)$  Since $a \lt 1$ the sum converges.  If we take a term-by-term derivative we get $-(ab)^n \sin (b^n \pi x)$, so if $b$ is large enough the sum will diverge.  It is continuous and nowhere differentiable.

Comment: yes the Weierstrass function is nowhere differentiable (and this of course means also almost everywhere). The almost everywhere part is not exactly addressed. What about the second part? How could one reason to come up with the Weierstrass function in the 1st place?

Comment: @NikosM.:  You can think of differentiation as a high pass filter.  The derivative of a sine wave gets multiplied by the frequency.  So you can make the function value converge while the derivative diverges.

Comment: Nice, how about the *almost everywhere* part, how can one reason for this in general? Of course the  cantor construction provides a way (construct a staircase), is the only one, or are there more or sth more general?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "how can one reason for this in general?"  This function is nowhere differentiable, not almost nowhere.  At the end of the Wikipedia article it remarks (with very little discussion) that among the continuous functions there are almost none that are differentiable even at one point.  Differentiablility is rare, but a very valuable property.

Comment: It means how did Weierstrass came up with such a construction. For example he could rely on the unboundness of the coefficients or sth else? This is the 2nd part of the question. Inded most functins are not differetiable. The answer you posted is close but could be improved

Comment: I think the hard part is to think it is possible that there is a continuous function with no derivative and important to find one.  When people draw a function on the board, it is usually differentiable, maybe not at a few points.  Once you decide to look for a nondifferentiable function, using high frequencies is a natural thing to do.

Comment: Ok, nice answer. How could one construct a function that is non-differentiable almost everywhere (instead of non-differetiable averywhere)?